# How to exit SurfaceView?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-canvas, surfaceview

I draw something on canvas using `SurfaceView`. How can I define a way to cancelling the surfaceView once the user is done? Below is my SurfaceView implementation. The `DrawOnTop` class has the `onDraw()` but I initialize all the variables in `Preview` class.

```
public class Preview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    SurfaceHolder mHolder;

    DrawOnTop mDrawOnTop;
    boolean mFinished;

    Preview(Context context, DrawOnTop drawOnTop) {
        super(context);

        mDrawOnTop = drawOnTop;
        mFinished = false;

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        //I set the bitmaps etc here
        mDrawOnTop.mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mDrawOnTop.mImageWidth,
                mDrawOnTop.mImageHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        mDrawOnTop.mBitmap.setPixels(mDrawOnTop.mRGBData, 0,
                mDrawOnTop.mImageWidth, 0, 0, mDrawOnTop.mImageWidth,
                mDrawOnTop.mImageHeight);
        Button x = new Button(getContext());
    x.setText("Hi");
    x.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


        }

    });
        mDrawOnTop.invalidate();

    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        mFinished = true;

    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {

    }

}
```

EDIT:

Now after some research I was able to find out that I need to use setContentView and set it back to the Activity I want.

Comment: what do you mean by exit from surfaceview?

Comment: I mean I want to get rid of everything that has been drawn

Comment: Can you post your code here,....

Comment: means after canvas drawn on Surface view want to back your activity??

Comment: Yes sir thats exactly what I want to do.

Comment: you can finish() your activity after your canvas drawn...

Comment: So where do I call finish()? How to check if canvas has finished drawing?

Comment: have you implemented setOnClickListener method for Preview  class??

Comment: Yes did now, check the updated code. I still cannot call finish() there.

Answer (score 1):

setvisibility to invisible to hide the view

```
setVisibility(this.Invisible);
```

Comment: This removes everything that was drawn however it gives me a black screen. I want it go back to `ActivityA`